# Is it possible to share modules between two or more Angular 6 projects or Apps?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have two Angular 6 projects say ProjectA(which has two modules ModuleA and ModuleB) and ProjectB. Can I access the ModuleA inside ProjectB ?

If possible then, how to export a module and inject it dynamically into another App ?

Comment: You'll need to package the modules as a library module, and then you can import the repackaged library module in your package.json

Answer (score 2):

If you can import the sources of ModuleA being in ProjectB, you can use it. It can be possible via relative path

```
import ModuleA from '../../ProjectA/src/ModuleA';
```

Also, you may publish your module on npm (say, "my-module-a"), add it as a dependency to both projects and then import it in a way

```
import ModuleA from 'my-module-a';
```

Answer (score 0):

Develop the module as a shared library, then import it as you would any other library.

All large organizations should have a shared library like this for any boilerplate code (auth clients, configurations, etc.)